# do I need to monitor zombies process in my redhat 7.9 server?

Tags: redhat, zombie

I have a 7.9 redhat server with around 30 users, 64 cores and 512 Go RAM. I have several zombies process, I don't know exactly what did user to create these but I have the feeling after reading stuff on internet that when their session is killed it will kill all zombies because the "parent" process will be killed.

so let's imagine that if a user create around 30 zombies during it's session, I could have 900 zombies process at maximum, it's only an approximation because the longer the session of one user will last, the higher the zombie process number will be. Do I need to monitor this number to avoid server crash or something like this ?

I know that zombie process don't take any ressource (RAM, CPU, etc.) but it is also an evidence that this value can't be higher than a limit...

I know also that sometimes user disconnect and then zombie process are cleaned so the number of zombie process could decrease...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, you certainly don't need to monitor them.**

That's the short answer. Although "zombie" might sound like something halfway dangerous that could potentially invade your system and cause all sorts of trouble, that's really not the case. A "zombie" process is not a process any more, so there's no way to "kill" them (not even SIGKILL will do anything). The process is already long dead and all its resources freed. A "zombie" is just a placeholder entry in the process table, keeping the process ID from being reused and storing the exit status of the dead process.

Such an entry will be removed when somebody calls one of the `wait*()` syscalls on the PID to retrieve the exit status ("reaping" the PID). That's normally what the parent would do immediately, so most zombies only stay around for milliseconds, but sometimes the parent forgets to do it for some reason, leaving you with a long-lived zombie. If the parent exits (that's your user logging out), the zombies will get reparented to the init process (PID 1, or a different process serving the same role), which will immediately reap anything it sees, cleaning the zombie up.

The amount of memory consumed by a zombie PID entry is trivial (tens of bytes), so it's not going to ever become an issue on any non-embedded system. You would need billions of zombies to consume a significant fraction of your RAM. So your only real worry is possibly exhausting the supply of process IDs if they all end up being hogged by zombies. The current limit on PIDs can be viewed and changed through `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` and it's set to at least 1024 times the number of cores or 32768, whichever is higher. You can raise it arbitrarily by writing to that file, up to a maximum of a little over 4 million.

So if your system is currently set to the default maximum of 65536 PIDs and you're worried about tens of thousands of zombies exhausting that, just raise the limit. To do that, create a file called `/etc/sysctl.d/somenameyoulike.conf` containing `kernel.pid_max = 1000000` (adjust value as desired). See `man sysctl.d` for details.